# Searching an NSSet attribute in CoreData with a searchbar

Tags: ios, search, core-data, uisearchbar, nspredicate

I have a CoreData model with an object "bar" which has a to-many relationship "drinks" to the entity "drink".

The entity drink has only one attribute called "name".

Now in my app I have a tableView that shows all the bars and has a searchBar included.

In this searchBar I would like to be able to search for the **name**, **location** and the possible **drinks** that are available in a bar.

I have already implemented the name and the location like this:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"
                                       name contains[cd] %@ OR
                       location.name_extern contains[cd] %@ OR 
                       location.name_intern contains[cd] %@", 
                            searchText, searchText, searchText];
```

So now my question is: How can I search for the name attribute in the NSSet of drinks?

EDIT:

To make it more clear, here are the important data models:

```
Bar

Attributes: 
name
location
drinks

Location

Attributes:
name_extern
name_intern

Drink:

Attributes:
name
```

I have a `searchText` and need to check the following 4 places whether it matches something:

1. name (of the Bar)
2. name_extern (of the Location of the Bar)
3. name_intern (of the Location of the Bar)
4. name (of ALL the drinks of the Bar)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"
                                       name contains[cd] %@ OR
                       location.name_extern contains[cd] %@ OR 
                       location.name_intern contains[cd] %@ OR
                   ANY location.drinks.name contains[cd] %@", 
                            searchText, searchText, searchText, searchText];
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea! But I think you misunderstood my question slightly. I'll edit the question again to make it more clear.

Comment: I hope it's more clear now.. I need to check for the name of the drinks whether it contains the searchText.. so I don't think your answer would work.